# How to make a field/property mandatory in Exact Synergy Enterprise?

Tags: database, exact-synergy-enterprise

I have created a custom table for my Repository using Exact SDT and uploaded it to the Exact Synergy Enterprise. How to set business component fields/properties to mandatory? For example, when users are filling a form in a page, fields should not be empty. Do SDT have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Repository Explorer` to accomplish this task.

Please go to `System` tab on the main page menu where `Customers`, `Documents`, etc. are located. In case you can not find it, please make sure you enabled it using `Preferences` found in the top right corner of your page. Go to `Menu` tab and see under the `Modules` section to add your menu item using arrow buttons.

Now  go to `System` tab, process to `Setup` tab  and under the `Repository` section click `Explorer`. Go to your `Repository` group, click your business component and choose a property you want to set as mandatory. You will see a `Validation` section and a drop down list. Set it to `Mandatory` and click Save.

Now go back to your `Repository group` and to click `XML` button. It will save all changes to your Repository XML file.